# Crazy $\int_0^{\frac\pi{2}}\frac {\cos\left((1-2n)\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt 2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{2}}}d\theta$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

$$\int_0^{\frac\pi{2}}\frac {\cos\left((1-2n)\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt 2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{(1-\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{2})}}d\theta$$

I tried using some sort of substitutions but I think this must have some other way to solve and gave me another different integral and gamma functions and all
which now I'm uncertain if it's my cup of tea!

Comment: Please show exactly what you did, providing ((much) more) context is part of the question. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question :: Explicitly: Which substitution did you try, and what computations were done after that, where did you get stuck in the middle? Which is the source of the problem? (And why is it important?!) Which is the question explicitly?

Comment: Is $n$ intended to be a positive integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}\int_0^{\frac\pi{2}}\frac {\cos\left((1-2n)\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt 2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{(1-\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{2})}}d\theta
& = \frac{\pi}{2}{_2F_1}{(1-n, n;1;\frac 1{2})}\\
& = \frac {\pi}{2}\frac {\sqrt \pi}{\Gamma(1-\frac n{2})\Gamma(\frac 1{2} + \frac n{2})}\\& = \frac {\pi}{2}P_{-n}(1-2x)|_{x = \frac 1{2}}\\
\end{align*}$$

---

- **In reply to the comment:**
  $\phi = \sin^{-1}(\sqrt x \sin(\theta))$
  $$\left|\int_0^{\sin^{-1}\sqrt x} \frac {\cos\left((1-2n)\phi\right)}{\sqrt{(x-\sin^2\phi)}}d\phi = \frac {\pi}{2}{_2F_1}(1-n,n;1;x)\right|_{x = \frac 1{2}}$$

---

- #Curiosity
  $$(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\cos(2n\sin^{-1} y) ={_2F_1}(\frac 1{2}+n, \frac 1{2}-n;\frac 1{2};y^2)$$
  $(y, 2n)  ≡ (\sqrt x \sin \theta, 1-2n)$ & integrating w.r.t $\theta$ over $(0, \pi/2)$

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: был сбит с толку $P_n$: Legendre Polynomial

Comment: Just out of curiosity : could you show me the steps for the first formula ? Thanks.

Comment: Would you like to explain? Please take your time

Comment: @SofiaIvanov Of course! but I thought you understood as you accepted the answer anyways Otherwise also I wanted to answer Claude's curiosity but please expect delay it's Monday now & I have lot of things to worry about on week days :))

Comment: I know your are an introvert (before you updated your profile) so thanks for adding your comment....

Comment: @Darshan P, just out of curiosity I wanted to ask if you are doing a PhD in math. I have seen your previous answers and loved them. They were elegant.

Comment: @SofiaIvanov Haha but on week days I become extrovert so it's really okay✌️

Comment: @RAHUL thanks Rahul ✌️ glad to hear so actually I wanted to do PhD but it's a long sad story I have done Mechanical engineering however I love maths in fact so much that I become so obsessed of it....+ Im dyslexic so I avoid lengthy explained answers

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos\left((1-2n)\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt 2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{(1-\frac{\sin^2\theta}2)}}\,d\theta$$
Let,
$$u=\arcsin\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{2}}\implies du=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{sin^2\theta}2}}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt2}d\theta$$
Multiply and divide by $\cos\theta$
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac {\cos\left((1-2n)\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{(1-\frac{\sin^2\theta}2)}}\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta$$
And note that if $u=\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt2}\right)$ then $\cos \theta=\sqrt{1-2\sin^{2} u}$
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos(u(1-2n))}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^{2} u}}du $$
By the double angle formulas we have $\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$.
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos(u(1-2n))}{\sqrt{\cos2u}}\,du$$
I hope you can go from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$I = \int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos{\left((1-2n)\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt x\sin(\phi)\right)\right)}}{\sqrt{(1-x\sin^2(\phi))}}d\phi$$

$$\begin{align*} (1-x^2)^{-\frac 1{2}}\cos(2n\sin^{-1}x)
& = _2F_1(0.5 + n, 0.5-n;0.5;x^2)\\
& = \text{let, }2n =1-2n \text{ & } x = \frac {\sin\phi}{\sqrt 2} \text {integrating both sides w.r.t } \phi \text{ over } \in [0, \pi/2]\\
\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {\cos{\left((1-2n)(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac {\sin\phi}-{\sqrt 2}\right)\right)}}{\sqrt{(1-\frac {\sin^2\phi}{2})}}d\phi
&=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} {_2F_1(1-n,n;0.5;\frac{\sin^2\phi}{2})}d\phi\\
& =\sum_{k\geq0}\frac {(1-n)_k(n)_k}{(0.5)_kk!2^k}\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}}{\sin^{2k}\phi}d\phi\\
& =\sum_{k\geq0}\frac {(1-n)_k(n)_k}{(0.5)_kk!2^k}\beta(0.5,k+0.5)\\
& =\sum_{k\geq0}\frac {(1-n)_k(n)_k}{\color{red}{(0.5)_k}k!2^k}\frac{\sqrt\pi\times \color{red}{\Gamma{(k+0.5)}}}{2\Gamma{(k+1)}}\\
& =\frac {\sqrt\pi}{2}\sum_{k\geq0} {\frac {(1-n)_k(n)_k}{(1)_k}\frac {(0.5)_k}{k!}}\\
& = \frac {\sqrt\pi}{2} {_2F_1}(1-n,n;1;0.5)\\
\end{align*}$$

You can use: $$ {_2F_1}(a, 1-a;b;0.5) = \frac {2^{1-b}\sqrt\pi \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma{(\frac{a+b}{2})}\Gamma{(\frac{b-a+1}{2})}}$$
(I don't know what this Identity is called nor do I remember where I read these all)

Now, Where I found that very first formula and all is other part of the story(I found that by differentiating 0.5sin(2narcsinx)/n = F(0.5+n,0.5-n;0.5;x^2)

**If any typo let it be  blamed in the name of Dyslexia**
Cheers:))

Comment: I know there must be some typo but I'm here to answer [Sir Claude's Curiosity](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici) as once he answered my [curiosity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4296486/crazy-int-0-frac-pi2-frac-cos-left1-2n-arcsin-left-frac-sin-theta/4296494#4296494)
With due humble I still doubt If I'm really the person good enough to answer such brilliant minds of MSE
 goodbye! StackCommunity! This was my last answer

Comment: I guess you can find these things in Ramanujan's lost notebook (either in chapter Hypergeometric function not sure which one (first/2nd)) or also one can check Elliptical function from same Ramanujan's Lost notebook (part- X) (Where you need to find the value of  "X")